# Structure of Backbone app. Model/Collection issues

Tags: backbone.js

Logic of my app is quite straightforward. I have Model that fetching JSONP (data contains years, quarter, and quarter contains different key:value). After fetching data, View listens for Model's "change" event and then rendering data. So far so good.

But then I need to listen for a "change:year"/"change:quarter" and fetch data with new url, based on changes. But when "change:year"/"change:quarter" fired, global "change" is fired also.

Sure, if I'll use Collection instead of Model – theres is "reset" for me. But in this case I can't listen for "change:year" so easily – I have to create few more Models (for year, quarter and each key in quarters). But I want to keep app simple.

Is there other way around? Or creating much more Model is inevitable?

Thanks.

UPD: "change" event still needed, because Model have to rerender, after fetching new data.

SOLUTION: I've created common Controller, that holds atributes, that needed to be changed. And in .url() method getting them from Controller to modify url. I stick to Collection's fetch()/"reset" notifying and made listener for Controller on "change". So, when I'm changing "year"/"quarter", View get notification from Controller, and when corresponding Collection fetching - it's fetching with new url.

Comment: Do you want that model's change event not fire when an attribute change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you, you don't want to receive the global model `change` event if only `year` or `quarter` changed - but you have to.

So instead when getting the receiving the global change event, you can check if it was only`year` or `quarter` that was [changed](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-changedAttributes), and the skip the normal event handling. Something like this:

```
this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
this.model.bind("change:year", this.fetchSomething, this);
this.model.bind("change:quarter", this.fetchSomething, this); 

render : function(){
    var attributesExceptYearAndQuarter = _.without(this.model.attributes, ['year', 'quarter']) 
    if(this.model.changedAttributes(attributesExceptYearAndQuarter).length > 0){
         // do the rendering
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. But I've found solution, that works better for my needs. But I'll keep your suggestion for future!

Answer (score 1):

You can check changed attributes in model's change listener.

```
var MyModel=Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize:function(){
      this.bind("change",this.changeModel);
      this.bind("change:year",this.changeYear);

   },
   changeModel:function(model,objs){
      //Checking changed attributes
      if (_.has(objs.changes,"year") || _.has(objs.changes,"quarter")) return this;

     console.log("Processing",objs.changes);
     return this;
  },
   changeYear:function(model,new_val){
    console.log("year changed.",new_val);
    return this;
  }

});


var mymodel=new MyModel();
mymodel.set("year",2012); 
mymodel.set("month",6);
```

If you have a view that listening model's change event, you should add a different attribute to the model and listen this attribute's change event instead of model's change event and render view when this attribute change. Change this attribute's value in changeModel function and fire listeners if your "year" and "quarter" attributes not in changed attributes as below.

```
//Edit changeModel as below
changeModel:function(model,objs){
          //Checking changed attributes
          if (_.has(objs.changes,"year") || _.has(objs.changes,"quarter")) return this;

          this.set("rerender",!this.rerender); //Changing for triggering change event
         return this;
      },


//View's constructor function
initialize:function(){
   this.model.bind("change:rerender",this.render);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort! That is also good workaround for my problem. But I'll stick for my solution - it's suits a little better for overall logic of my app.

Comment: Well.How to solve the problem,can you share with us? Maybe we will be encountered same problem in the future.

Comment: I've described it in SOLUTION.